# Automatic Soundcloud PHP Api authentication without user interaction

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

In my application i want to use the Soundcloud API with my own Soundcloud user. The Soundcloud API authentication process involves a user being redirected to the Soundcloud homepage, login and authorize the application, so that the page can use the API for this user.

I want to automate the whole process, because my own user is the only user which gets authenticated. Is that possible?

Here is my code so far:

```
    $soundcloud = new \Services_Soundcloud(
        '**',
        '**',
        'http://**'
    );

    $authorizeUrl = $soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl();

    $accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken();

    try {
        $me = json_decode($soundcloud->get('me'), true);
    } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
```

But the line `$accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken();` throws an exception:

```
The requested URL responded with HTTP code 401.
500 Internal Server Error - Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for the same thing, but according to the [soundcloud's api](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication) (check the *Authenticating without the SoundCloud Connect Screen* paragraph):

```
// this example is not supported by the PHP SDK
```

..and is not supported by the Javascript neither.

I've tryed to auth with python:

```
# create client object with app and user credentials
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
                           client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
                           username='YOUR_USERNAME',
                           password='YOUR_PASSWORD')
```

..then the uploading python method:

```
# upload audio file
track = client.post('/tracks', track={
    'title': 'This is my sound',
    'asset_data': open('file.mp3', 'rb')
})
```

and it works just fine.

So, for now, you have 2 ways:

1. Use another language, Python or Ruby (the only 2 sdk that actually support this feature) or use a small python/ruby script as a bridge for this particular need;
2. Add this funcionaliy to the PHP SDK (i'm trying to do it quick'n'dirty, if i get success, i'll share ;)

Comment: I am agree with Strae. The PHP SDK doesn't work perfectly. It is throwing 401 error when we are trying to get access token.

Comment: I have to say I failed to add this functionality in the php SDK

Answer (score 4):

> Hi All,
>
> Here I am going to share my experience with Soundcloud API (PHP)

See my Question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647791/sound-cloud-returning-401-error/14699899#14699899)

```
Recently I started to work with Sound cloud API (PHP) and I decided to use PHP API by

https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud.

But When I was trying to get access token from Sound cloud server by this code:
```

> ```
> // Get access token
> try {
>     $accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken($_GET['code']);
> } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
>     exit($e->getMessage());
> }
> ```
>
> I had check the $_GET['code'] value. But strange there is nothing in
>   $_GET['code']  this is blank. The Soundcloud was returning "The
>   requested URL responded with HTTP code 0" error. That time I was
>   testing Soundcloud on WAMP Localhost.
>
> Allot of Goggling I found a solution to fix "The requested URL
>   responded with HTTP code 0" issue. I had download 'cacert.pem' file
>   and put inside our demo project folder (inside Services/Soundcloud/).
>   Then after I added some code in 'class Services_Soundcloud'
>
> ```
> function protected function _request($url, $curlOptions = array()).
> // My code in side function
> $curlPath = realpath(getcwd().'\Services\cacert.pem');         
> $curlSSLSertificate = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $curlPath);        
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $curlSSLSertificate);
> ```
>
> Saved 'class Services_Soundcloud' file and moved on live server. After
>   move my project from WAMP to Live server I start to check it again.
>   When I open my index.php it's ask me to login

[image]

```
I use my Facebook account to login.
```

[image]

```
after login it was asking to connect with Soundcloud
```

[image]

> after connect everything working smooth, I got my info with

```
$me = json_decode($soundcloud->get('me'));
```

> but a new problem start to occurring which was that my access token
>   being expire again and again. Then I use session :D

```
// code for access token
$code = $_GET['code'];
// Get access token
try {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
        $accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken($code);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['access_token'];
    }else{
        $soundcloud->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }   
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

And now everything working awesome. i can get all my details, tracks everything from SC server

Hope it will help you to fight with Soundcloud API Cheers!!!! :)

Comment: Hi Alp Please check my answer and kindly let me know if it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic behind its implementation in Python and Ruby SDK's.
What's happening is that `POST` request is sent to `http://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token` with the following params:

```
   client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
   client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
   username='YOUR_USERNAME'
   password='YOUR_PASSWORD'
```

And `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

The response body contains `access_token`, that can be used for the further authorization of your requests. Thus, your `GET` request to `/me` endpoint will look like: `/me?oauth_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`. (I believe, `client_id` is redundant here but all their apps keep adding it).

Here is the Postman Doc I created for demonstration: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3651572/soundcloud/7TT5oD9